Prove that a mapping $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ preserves directional derivatives.
This is an exercise from Elementary Differential Geometry - Barrett O'Neill.
Let $v_p$ a tangent vector to $\mathbb{R}^n$, $g:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function, $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$. We suppose $F$ is also differentiable (in the $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ sense). $F=(f_1,\ldots,f_m)$.
I'm trying to prove that $F$ preserves directional derivatives, i.e. $F{*}(v_p)[g]=v_p[g(F)]$, where $F{*}$ is the tangent map of $F$.
Here's my attemp:
Let $u:=F{*}(v_p)$.
\begin{align*}
F{*}(v_p)[g]&=u[g]=\sum\limits_{j=1}^mu_j\frac{\partial g}{\partial y_j}(F(p))=\sum\limits_{j=1}^m v[f_j]\frac{\partial g}{\partial y_j}(F(p))\\
&=\sum\limits_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^n v_i\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}(p)\frac{\partial g}{\partial y_j}(F(p))
\end{align*}
where $u_i=v[f_i]$ since $F{*}(v)=(v[f_1],\ldots,v[f_m])$ at $F(p)$. I'm aware I can expand $v[f_j]$ more explicitly.
On the other hand, let $h=g\circ F$
\begin{align*}
v_p[g(F)]&=v_p[g\circ F]=v_p[h]=\sum_{i=1}^nv_i\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x_i}(p)=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\dfrac{\partial(g\circ F)}{\partial x_i}(p)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\sum_{j=1}^m\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y_j}(F(p))\dfrac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}(p)=\sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\dfrac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}(p)\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y_j}(F(p))
\end{align*}
I'm not applying the chain rule since the derivative of $F$ would be a vector, and something is not matching because above $F{*}(v_p)[g]$ is a number.
Edit: I corrected the original question, I was struggling with chain rule and indexes, gonna post the answer.

What is your question?

You do need to write out the chain rule. However, I recommend that you stop using $x_i$ as coordinates in both $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^m$. You should also notice that the problem is mis-stated: If $g\colon\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$, then $g\circ F$ is not defined. Once you get that fixed, use $x_i$ as coordinates in $\Bbb R^n$ and $y_j$ as coordinates in $\Bbb R^m$.

@TedShifrin The $n$ in $g$ was a typo, it was indeed $m$. By stop using $x_i$ coordinates you mean that i use different indexes in both spaces, like $i,j$, get it. When I apply the chain rule, $\frac{\partial g\circ F}{\partial x_i}$, will I get the derivative of $g$ evaluated in $F$ times $F$ derivative with respecto to the variable? But $F$ is a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, so it is a vector where each vector is differentiated with respect to the corresponding variable?

@uniquesolution my question is the problem of dimensiones in the equalities I need.

So edit your post to include the correct variables, indices, and index ranges. Then decide what $v(f_j)$ is.

I just fixed many things you pointed out, I have left to think about the chain rule.

I could figure it out! Being careful with indexes and applying the chain rule properly was enough to get the result. Thank you @TedShifrin.

Looks good. Now just delete your sentence at the end. I guess I should have told you to post this as an answer!

Let $u:=F{*}(v_p)$.
\begin{align*}
F{*}(v_p)[g]&=u[g]=\sum\limits_{j=1}^mu_j\frac{\partial g}{\partial y_j}(F(p))=\sum\limits_{j=1}^m v[f_j]\frac{\partial g}{\partial y_j}(F(p))\\
&=\sum\limits_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^n v_i\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}(p)\frac{\partial g}{\partial y_j}(F(p))
\end{align*}
where $u_j=v[f_j]$ since $F{*}(v)=(v[f_1],\ldots,v[f_m])$ at $F(p)$. I'm aware I can expand $v[f_j]$ more explicitly.
On the other hand, let $h=g\circ F$
\begin{align*}
v_p[g(F)]&=v_p[g\circ F]=v_p[h]=\sum_{i=1}^nv_i\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x_i}(p)=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\dfrac{\partial(g\circ F)}{\partial x_i}(p)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\sum_{j=1}^m\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y_j}(F(p))\dfrac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}(p)=\sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\dfrac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}(p)\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y_j}(F(p)).
\end{align*}
